# Tmux lost server problem

Tags: tmux

My question is about TMUX lost-server issue.
Can anyone please help me out on how to resolve the lost server issue?
I accidently killed the server using **tmux kill-server** command.

Comment: So you killed the tmux-server and it died ... I think that it works as designed. What are your exact question ?

Answer (score 3):

```
tmux start-server
```

should start it again.

Comment: I didnt start the server for me.

Comment: Answer: it's trying to talk to a socket connection in the `/tmp/tmux-####` directory where that's ### is a number. Find the ones owned by you. This wasn't properly cleaned up so remove them and try again.